# How can I make sure that a file inside a Dropbox is really gone after delete?

Tags: c#, io, dropbox, windows-server

I am using files inside a Dropbox to communicate between Servers. After a while I realized that every once in a while there is a delay in the basic `File` operations when executed on a file inside the Dropbox.

What I need is something like this:

```
public class MyFile
{
    const int maxWaitCount = 60;
    //..
    /// <summary>
    /// remove file - also has to work inside Dropbox directory
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>0 for ok or error code</returns>
    public int rm()
    {
        string name = Os.winInternal(FullName);
        if (File.Exists(name))
        {
            File.Delete(name);
            #region double check if file is gone
            if (Ensure)
                return awaitFileVanishing(name);
            #endregion
        }
        return 0;
    }
    //..
    private int awaitFileMaterializing(string fileName) //..
    private int awaitFileVanishing(string fileName) //..
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor: auto-ensure mode for file systems that do not synchronously wait for the end of an IO operation i.e. Dropbox
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>only use the ensure mode if it has to be guaranteed that the IO operation was completely done
    /// when the method call returns; necessary e.g. for Dropbox directories since (currently) Dropbox first updates the
    /// file in the invisible . folder and then asynchronously updates the visible file and all the remote copies of it</remarks>
    /// <param name="filename"></param>
    public MyFile(string filename)
    {
        Ensure = filename.ToLower().Contains("dropbox");
        // ..
    }
}
```

Since I needed a quick solution, I came up with one that I am presenting as an answer to my own question below. However, I can easily imagine that some of you had this problem as well and found a different, possibly more compelling solution. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution for `awaitFileMaterializing` and `awaitFileVanishing` as used as part of `MyFile`.

```
    private int awaitFileMaterializing(string fileName)
    {
        int count = 0;
        bool exists = false;
        while (count < maxWaitCount)
        {
            try
            {
                exists = File.Exists(fileName);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }   // device not ready exception if Win 2003
            if (exists)
                break;
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            count++;
        }
        if (count >= maxWaitCount)
            throw new FileNotFoundException("ensure failed - timeout.", fileName);
        return -count;
    }
    private int awaitFileVanishing(string fileName)
    {
        int count = 0;
        bool exists = true;
        while (count < maxWaitCount)
        {
            try
            {
                exists = File.Exists(fileName);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }   // device not ready exception if Win 2003
            if (!exists)
                break;
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            count++;
        }
        if (count >= maxWaitCount)
            throw new IOException("ensure failed - timeout in deleting " + fileName + ".");
        return -count;
    }
```

Comment: Instead of sleeping the thread, I think it is better to use asynchronous delay so the thread can be fully utilized by doing something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor your Dropbox folder.  FileSystemWatcher has a deleted event that you can attach to that tells you when a file has been deleted from the folder being watched.

[MSDN Source & Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sounds like you are recommending an event driven way to deal with it, Dmitry. Would certainly change the whole programming model in my case. I was hoping more for some await style idea or solution here.

Comment: I thought about it Dmitry and I would now want to add: I am a huge fan of using the observer pattern for propagation of changes. However, in the above referenced context I just want to delete a file and have to await until it's finally done to proceed with the next action (like creating the file again with the same name but different content). So, I am sitting in a sync position and await the previously initiated action to finish up.